# Postgresql - can you do this without a CTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to get the number of orders and money spent by customers in the first 7 days from their initial order. I managed to do it with a common table expression, but was curious to see if someone could point out to an obvious update to the main query's WHERE or HAVING section, or perhaps a subquery.

```
--This is a temp table to use in the main query
WITH first_seven AS 

    (
    select min(o.created_at), min(o.created_at) + INTERVAL '7 day' as max_order_date, o.user_id
    from orders o
    where o.total_price > 0 and o.status = 30
    group by o.user_id
    having min(o.created_at) > '2015-09-01' 
    )


--This is the main query, find orders in first 7 days of purchasing

SELECT sum(o.total_price) as sales, count(distinct o.objectid) as orders, o.user_id, min(o.created_at) as first_order
from orders o, first_seven f7 
where o.user_id = f7.user_id and o.created_at < f7.max_order_date and o.total_price > 0 and o.status = 30
group by o.user_id
having min(o.created_at) > '2015-09-01'
```

Comment: No one can help you if you don't give at least your table DDL, some data sample, the expected result and your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: You can turn it into a subquery, if you like.  By the way, never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: It's just a standard table of transactions, orderid, customerid, orderdate and totalprice

Comment: The best query depends on the table definition. Always provide your version of Postgres and the table definition showing data types and constraints: A `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d orders` in psql. The question is hardly useful for others without basic information. The data type of  `created_at` is particularly important.

Comment: thanks @ErwinBrandstetter - I had not thought to include those details but will in the future. Good insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without the `join` by using window functions:

```
select sum(o.total_price) as sales, count(distinct o.objectid) as orders,
       o.user_id, min(o.created_at) as first_order
from (select o.*,
             min(o.created_at) over (partition by user_id) as startdate
      from orders o
      where o.total_price > 0 and o.status = 30 
     ) o
where startdate > '2015-09-01' and
      created_at <= startdate + INTERVAL '7 day';
```

A more complicated query (with the right indexes) is probably more efficient:

```
select sum(o.total_price) as sales, count(distinct o.objectid) as orders,
       o.user_id, min(o.created_at) as first_order
from (select o.*,
             min(o.created_at) over (partition by user_id) as startdate
      from orders o
      where o.total_price > 0 and o.status = 30 and
            not exists (select 1 from orders o2 where o2.user_id = o.user_id and created_at <= '2015-09-01')
     ) o
where startdate > '2015-09-01' and
      created_at <= startdate + INTERVAL '7 day';
```

This filters out older customers before the windows calculation, which should make it more efficient.  Indexes that are useful are `orders(user_id, created_at)` and `orders(status, total_price)`.